# How are the call and put slopes in the SVI-JW parametrization derived?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, parameter

In the SVI-JW parametrization, we have

$$
w(k; a, b, \rho, m, \sigma) = a + b \left [ \rho(k-m) + \sqrt{(k-m)^{2} + \sigma^{2}} \right ]
$$

Which gives us

$$
\begin{align*}
\sigma_{BS}(k) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\sqrt{a + b \left [ \rho(k-m) + \sqrt{(k-m)^{2} + \sigma^{2}} \right ]} \\
\\
\\
\frac{\partial \sigma_{BS}}{\partial k} &= \frac{b\left [\rho + \frac{(k - m)}{\sqrt{(k-m)^{2} + v^2}}\right ]}{2\sqrt{t}\sqrt{a + b \left [ \rho(k-m) + \sqrt{(k-m)^{2} + \sigma^{2}} \right ]}}
\end{align*}
$$

We can evaluate ATM variance $v_{t}$ by setting $k=0$ in $w(k; a, b, \rho, m, \sigma)$, we can evaluate ATM skew $\psi_{t}$ by evaluating $\frac{\partial \sigma_{BS}}{\partial k}|_{k=0}$ and we can evaluate minimum implied variance $\tilde{v}_{t}$ by setting $\frac{\partial \sigma_{BS}}{\partial k} = 0$  and plugging $k$ into $w(k)$.

How can we find the put and call slopes $p_{t}$ and $c_{t}$? I assumed it would be the limit of the variance $\frac{w(k)}{t}$ when $k \rightarrow \pm \infty$ but this gives me $\frac{b}{\sqrt{t}}(\rho \pm 1)$ which does not match Gatheral's results in his original paper.

Link to original paper *Arbitrage-free SVI volatility surfaces* by Jim Gatheral,  Antoine Jacquier [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

$(p_t,c_t)$ are respectively related to the put/call slopes of the total implied variance, not variance $$ w(k,t)=\sigma^2(k,t) t $$

Under SVI
$$ w(k) = a + b \left(\rho(k-m) + \sqrt{(k-m)^2 + \sigma^2} \right) $$
such that
$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial k}(k) = b \left( \rho + \frac{k-m}{\sqrt{(k-m)^2+\sigma^2}} \right) $$
and
$$ \lim_{k \to \pm \infty} \frac{\partial w}{\partial k}(k) = b \left( \rho \pm 1 \right) $$
(see also [here end of p.5](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02517572/document))

Now, remembering should you define:
$$ p_t := \frac{1}{\sqrt{w_t}} b (1-\rho) $$
$$ c_t := \frac{1}{\sqrt{w_t}} b (1+\rho) $$
with $w_t$ the ATMF total implied variance ($w_t = v_t t$ in the JW space) then you have that indeed:

- $p_t$ is proportional to the opposite of the put slope of total implied variance and is expected to be positive (because $w_t$ and $b$ are positive)
- $c_t$ is proportional to the call slope of total implied variance and is expected to be positive (because $w_t$ and $b$ are positive)

Comment: However the original paper has definitions for ($c_{t}$, $p_{t}$) of $\frac{b}{\sqrt{w_{t}}} (1 \pm \rho)$ where $w_{t} = w(0, t)$. Where is the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{w_{t}}}$ term coming from? And why is the sign different for $p_{t}$?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer to make it clearer. The term $1/\sqrt{w_t}$ is basically a scaling term. And indeed, $p_t \propto -\text{put slope}$ and $c_t \propto +\text{call slope}$.